# aws amazon linux gui using vnc error (EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

very new to AWS, so sorry if it's a dumb Q.

link ref: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-2-install-gui/

last step says:

```sh
"Use the -L parameter to enable port forwarding. Replace PEM_FILE with the path for your private key. Replace INSTANCE_IP with your instance's public or private IP, as appropriate.
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 -i PEM_FILE ec2-user@INSTANCE_IP"
```

so i have put it in a notepad:

`ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 -i C:\Users\tlech\Documents\aws/AWS.pem ec2-user@[my instance private ip]`

where do i paste this command? normal cmd or in putty? when i post it in putty i get an error:

```sh
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the command in the cmd prompt of Windows. Alternatively you can install [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) which will give you a bash prompt where you can run it as well.

your command would become

`ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 -i C:\\Users\\tlech\\Documents\\aws\\AWS.pem ec2-user@[instance_public_ip]`